# Layered pane isn't work after once

Tags: java, swing

This is code of my graphical represetation but problem is that lpane calls once but when i again pres the start again and it does not constructor of casino calls but ihave checked console program also works but lpane does not change the cards.........

```
package test;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Test() {
        initComponents();
         start.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

                new Casino();
                new JLayeredPane();
                System.out.println(Casino.p[0].getpHand()[0].getValue());
            }
        });
    }
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        start = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lpane = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        start.setText("Start");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jLayeredPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(lpane);
        lpane.setLayout(jLayeredPane1Layout);
        jLayeredPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 691, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jLayeredPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 475, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(start)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(lpane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(114, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(lpane)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(start)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {


        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static JLayeredPane getLPane(){
    return lpane;
}


    private static javax.swing.JLayeredPane lpane;
    private static javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private static javax.swing.JButton start;

}
```

Comment: Need code of `Casino`

Comment: package test;

public class Casino {
    public Casino(){
        p = new Players[4];
        new DealAndShuffle();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            p[i] = new Players();
            if(i==0) p[i].loadButtons(20, 30,0);
            else if(i==1)p[i].loadButtons(50, 10,1);
            else if(i==2)p[i].loadButtons(360, 30,2);
            else p[i].loadButtons(50, 350,3);
        }
    }
   public static Players[] p; 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step back for a second and have a look at your `mouseClicked` event...

```
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

                new Casino();
                new JLayeredPane();
                System.out.println(Casino.p[0].getpHand()[0].getValue());
            }
```

You create a new instance of `Casino` and `JLayeredPane` and do thing with it, they aren't even assigned to some kind of reference...

Do not rely on `static` references, they are a clear sign of a bad design...

Don't use `MouseListener`s on buttons, you should be using an `ActionListener`

Step away from the form designer, seriously, it's doing you harm.  Take the time to read through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), understand how to build UIs by hand and the tricks you need to produce complex interfaces, only then will you understand what the form designer can do for you and how to use it.